# How to get response in php from papal IPN

Tags: php, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I have created an paypal's ipn response & now i want to know to how can i get the response in php by using **GET** or **POST**. I am doing this for the first time . So, i have no idea what to do next when i get the ipn response.
Suggest some method to capture paypal IPN data properly.
Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
    class Paypal_IPN
    {
        public function __construct($mode= 'live')
        {
            //https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr
            if($mode == 'live'){
            $this->_url = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';}
            else{
            $this->_url = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';  }  


        }

        public function run()
        {
            $postFields = 'cmd=_notify-validate';


            foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
            {
                $postFields .= "&$key=".urlencode($value);
            }

            $ch = curl_init();

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->_url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

            $result = curl_exec($ch);

            curl_close($ch);

            $fh = fopen('result.txt','w');
            fwrite($fh, $result . '--' . $postFields);
            fclose($fh);
            echo "abc";
            echo $result; 
        }

    }

?>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, the title suggests you don't have a response from IPN but the description states you don't know what to do with the response

Comment: The response you get is in JSON format. No one here can tell you what to do with it because depending on what `POST` you are sending the api; the return changes vastly... https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/

Answer (score 0):

Recently I was used paypal IPN in a website. So I can help you.
Here is the code working for me. Let me know if it helps you.

```
class Paypal_IPN
{
    public $_url;
    public function __construct($mode= 'live')
    {
        //https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr
        if($mode == 'live'){
            $this->_url = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
        }else{
            $this->_url = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
        }
    }
    public function run(){
        // STEP 1: Read POST data
        // reading posted data from directly from $_POST causes serialization 
        // issues with array data in POST
        // reading raw POST data from input stream instead. 
        $raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
        $raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
        $myPost = array();
        foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
          $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
          if (count($keyval) == 2)
             $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
        }
        // read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
        $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
        if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
           $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
        }
        foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {    
           if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) { 
                $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value)); 
           } else {
                $value = urlencode($value);
           }
           $req .= "&$key=$value";
        }


        // STEP 2: Post IPN data back to paypal to validate

        $ch = curl_init($this->_url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

        // In wamp like environments that do not come bundled with root authority certificates,
        // please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set the directory path 
        // of the certificate as shown below.
        // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem');
        if( !($res = curl_exec($ch)) ) {
            // error_log("Got " . curl_error($ch) . " when processing IPN data");
            curl_close($ch);
            exit;
        }
        curl_close($ch);


        // STEP 3: Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly

        if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
            // check whether the payment_status is Completed
            // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
            // check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
            // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
            // process payment

            // assign posted variables to local variables like below
            // just an example. Visit paypal ipn variables for more details
            $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
            $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
            $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
            $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
            $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
            $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
            $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
            $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];

            // <---- HERE you can do your INSERT to the database
            //Your code here.
        } else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
            // log for manual investigation
        }

    }
}
```